# Running functions consecutively

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a Google Apps script as a web app - which creates a Google Doc by iterating through JSON data.  Once completed, the same script creates a PDF and saves it to Google Drive.

But I am struggling with the "Once completed" part - as, for some reason - though the function I call to create the PDF is the last instruction in the script - it creates the PDF before the function that creates the document completes - resulting in a blank PDF.

I have stepped through each line of code using the debugger - and it seems that the document is only fully populated when the final line of code runs.  Which is no good to me as that results in a blank PDF.

I have tried adding promises, but they seem to be ignored.

it really is as if the script is waiting to fully complete, before the function that populates the document finishes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  My only option at the moment is to run two entirely separate scripts - one which makes the document and another that makes the PDF.  That works, but feels like a clunky work around

Any help much appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your code so the community will have better information on your project and have your question get better chance of getting answered.

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

You are correct in your assumption that the contents of the document are saved only after running the last line of the code. We won't be able to properly debug your code without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it. However, I recommend checking out the `saveAndClose()` method which should populate the doc before the code finished running. You should ideally add that method at the end of the function that populates the Google Doc.

### Reference:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)